# "No records of type '' found" error - shortcode in WordPress page to edit profile

Tags: wordpress, profile

Help - updating profile forms from the front-end has broken over the last few updates. I have the following shortcode used on a Wordpress page:

```
[civicrm component="profile" gid="14" mode="edit" hijack="0"]
```

Upon viewing the page, I get the ""No records of type '' found" error:
[image]

If the shortcode is set to "view", it displays fine.

This occurs with me logged in with admin privileges.

Ideas?

Comment: Which version of Civicrm are you using??

Comment: Oops, sorry, I'm using CiviCRM 4.6.8 and WordPress 4.3.1.

Comment: Would still really like some help with this! Any ideas?

Comment: hi Penny - I tried to run the same but I didn't get any error message - so I guess you are doing something wrong - Is their anyway you can send me the link which you are working On - just for testing

Comment: Hi Ramesh, sorry for not replying - I've been away! The site is http://mltawa.asn.au and the forms are for updating membership information (profiles). It's still occuring and I'd love to fix it before our membership round (next month).

Comment: Getting the same issue on 4.7.3 WordPress 4.5.2. Records are shown if shown "inline" but in a tab, after adding records, the message "No records of type '' found." is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Doh! Not sure if this is what others found, but I'm ashamed to say the error message:

> "No records of type '' found."

is shown when none of the fields in the Custom Data set are set to "Display in table" (!)