# Home page redirecting to event page on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm running Wordpress 4.4.1 and CiviCRM 4.6.11

The main page of our site http://www.mltawa.asn.au is redirecting to an old event's page (http://mltawa.asn.au/2015-agm-registration/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/info&reset=1&id=7). When I disable the event, it goes into a loop or, if logged in as admin, I get the pop-up message in the back-end:

> The event you requested is currently unavailable (contact the site
>   administrator for assistance).

Ideas of where to start looking to fix this? :)

Comment: Can you go to Administer - System Settings - CMS Database Integration and tell what's in "WordPress Base Page"?

Comment: Ya, it's just set to the default - it's blank atm.

Comment: so, nothing in the text field?

Comment: That's correct. Sometimes I get this error "Exception thrown GAPI: Failed to authenticate user. Error: "https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps " I don't know where to start looking...

Comment: If I deactivate the CiviCRM plugin, it's all fine, so I know there's some box somewhere I need to tick or untick or change!

Comment: Could this other problem I'm having with displaying forms be related, I wonder? http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6756/no-records-of-type-found-error-shortcode-in-wordpress-page-to-edit-profil

Comment: I have a similar problem with WP on a mobile phone (Android). I type the home page URL into a browser [bio4climate.org](http://bio4climate.org) and it bounces me to a blog post. I can't get to the home page (which is a post, not a page), it always redirects. I have no redirection anywhere in the code as far as I know. I've tried two mobile plug-ins (WordApp and one other), same result. The WordApp developer (Dave Anthony) said he'd take a look but apparently gave up. I'm running Civi 4.7.7, WP 4.4.4 with 2012 theme. Redirect doesn't happen on a Windows 7 laptop or other machines as far as I kn

Comment: I have tested this in production (Civi 4.7.27 on Wordpress 4.9.1), and a fresh test install (Civi 4.7.29 on Wordpress 4.9.2). It appears to be a bug. The problem occurs if the Wordpress post uses the civi code for the **registration** page, not the **info** page. This seems to be triggered by the registration profile no longer being visible due to the event being booked out or having ended. There are two possible workarounds: 1. Use an **Info page** rather than going direct to the Registration page (RECOMMENDED). An info page will automatically include a link to a registration page, but doing

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty Wordpress page, name it what you want, for example "civi". 
Add that name to the "WordPress Base Page" in 
Administer - System Settings - CMS Database Integration.

For more info see:
http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Displaying+Public+Forms+in+WordPress+Frontend+Sites

Does that work?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: hmm, what happens if you go 
http://mltawa.asn.au/2015-agm-registration

Does that page exist also when CiviCRM is disabled?

Comment: Yes - the page exists, and then just displays the header image and shortcode for the form.

Comment: Another thing I can think about is something weird in Wordpress Settings - Reading - Front Page settings.

Comment: I see the  "normal" front page now, it seems like
[civicrm component=”event” id=”7″ action=”register” mode=”live” hijack=”0″] is somehow taking over command and forwards to the page. What happens if you delete this component from that page when you activate CiviCRM?

Comment: Ya, it's because I deactivated CiviCRM. I also reset the theme earlier thinking that help but alas, no (and I lost all my little tweaks - oops).

Comment: Removing the form from the post did the trick! But I wonder if it's going to occur again if I set up another form for another event in a post. Will test tomorrow. Perhaps there's a conflict and forms need to go in pages, not posts.