# Profile Displaying "No Record of Type found"

Tags: profile, gift-aid-extension

I have a profile for updating people's details - set up via a short code in Wordpress in the view only mode the Data set displays fine See below  -  when I switch to edit mode it comes up with the following with No record of Type Found

[image]

If you click on the Add New record it comes up with a box to edit it -  Is it possible to get it to appear in an inline format? What Have I missed?

It does relate to the Gift Aid, I have checked in the Custom Data fields "display as Table is checked" as per ["No records of type '' found" error - shortcode in WordPress page to edit profile](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6756/no-records-of-type-found-error-shortcode-in-wordpress-page-to-edit-profil)

Its worth noting that the Gift Aid field do not dispaly when searching for fields or on the tokens when creating emails - Am guessing this is setting somewhere?

In View Mode
[image]

Civi 5.65.2 On wordpress 6.4.1 Uk Gift Aid  Extension 3.5.3

Answer (score 1):

The message means that there isn't any record for Gift Aid for the contact.

Comment: There is  as both of the above screen grabs were created for the same contact

Comment: Having done some more digging I think this is because the custom Field Set "allows Multiple Records" hence why it is wanting to add a new one